# Node form elements don't work when inserted with Panels. Am I missing something?

Tags: panels, entities, nodes

What I have done:

- Created a Panels variant for viewing a node.
- Added a Context relationship to the node edit form.
- Added a form element with the relationship.
- Added the node save button with the relationship.
- Verified that I can see and interact with the widget and buttons.

What I expected:
 - Updating the field widget and then pressing "save" would save the node with the new value set by the widget

What I experienced:
 - Pressing "save" after entering a value in the widget didn't seem to do anything but reload the page on one of my content types.
 - On another content type it works as expected.

I suspect that some of the vast amount of custom code on my site is breaking it somewhere, but I'm not experienced enough with Panels/Ctools to know where to start looking. The node save button still works fine for all content types from the node/nid/edit page.

Comment: Does it work if you create a variant for node edit, with only the node edit widget? I seem to recall I've successfully combined view and edit before, but there could be some weird interaction there. Try breaking it down into a smaller task to identify what goes wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if you miss understand because I accidentally posted half a comment, and that's what you've read, or if I'm unclear, so here goes: On the page overview, activate node/%/edit (instead of node/%). Set up a new variant, and include only the full node edit form. Does that work?

Comment: I have to go AFK for a few minutes, but if you hang around in the chat a while, I might be able to help better.

Comment: Apparently it works on one of my content types but not on another, similar one. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Perhaps that some other module interferes?